# Flutter Riverpod Future provider - requires async and await?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod, flutter-future

I've been reviewing the RiverPod 2 tutorial at https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/

In the section dealing with Future providers there is a code snippet as shown below...

```
final weatherFutureProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<Weather>((ref) {
  // get repository from the provider below
  final weatherRepository = ref.watch(weatherRepositoryProvider);
  // call method that returns a Future<Weather>
  return weatherRepository.getWeather(city: 'London');
});
```

I can't understand why this code snippet is missing the 'async' and 'await' syntax as shown below...

```
final weatherFutureProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<Weather>((ref) async {
  // get repository from the provider below
  final weatherRepository = ref.watch(weatherRepositoryProvider);
  // call method that returns a Future<Weather>
  return await weatherRepository.getWeather(city: 'London');
});
```

Is my version correct or what?

Answer (score 4):

Think of it as doing:

```dart
Future<int> example() {
  return Future.value(42);
}
```

instead of:

```dart
Future<int> example() async {
  return await Future.value(42);
}
```

Sure, you can use `async`/`await`. But it is technically optional here.

Doing `return future` vs `return await future` doesn't change anything. In fact, there's a lint for removing the unnecessary `await`: [unnecessary_await_in_return](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unnecessary_await_in_return.html)

The `async` keyword is generally helpful. It catches exceptions in the function and converts them into a `Future.error`.
But `FutureProvider` already takes care of that. So `async` could also be omitted

Comment: Oh interesting, so this is a dart feature that it awaits futures instead of returning them?